# Copy all objects inside folder from same bucket AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-step-functions

I'm trying to make backups of my data on a daily basis. I'm trying to create a Step Function which copy all objects inside some path, and move it (renamed) to another path basically.

Based on the following post: [AWS Stepfunctions - Copy files between buckets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68655394/aws-stepfunctions-copy-files-between-buckets) I've tried to do it, but I don't manage to copy all objects inside an S3 path.

Is there a way to use somehow a "*" on CopySource parameter?

Imagine that the S3 path contains subsequent folders with several parquet files on each folder.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I would recommend having a look at AWS Backup if you haven't already. It's a no (additional) cost service that appears to fit your use case.

Comment: Thank you! I will take a look. Do you know any solution that could fit in a Step Function with a ListObjects and a CopyObject operation?